# Space before command circumvents DOSKEY

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I wanted keep my users from running "dir" in the command line, so I used DOSKEY to alias "Dir" to "CLS".  The testers found out that putting a space before "DIR" will circumvent the alias.

I've tried to put a space before "DIR" when setting up the DOSKEY, but the command prompt ignores the white space.

Anyone found a way of making DOSKEY acknowledge spaces?

Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? Also, to answer your specific question, you cannot make DOSKEY macro names with spaces and even if you could, how do you want to avoid that the user enters 2,10 or 1000 spaces before? If you tell us what exactly it is you want to achieve, maybe there is a better solution...

Comment: Whatever this alias is a solution for... needs a different solution.

Comment: the last time I had to deny users access to an internal command, I used a hex editor on `COMMAND.COM`... I have no idea how well that would work today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deny your users the *List Directory contents* permission on all relevant locations. That's probably the easier way. That way they can run `dir` but it won't be of any use.

I'm not even trying to figure out why you want such a thing, though.

Regarding `doskey`: As you noticed, macro substituion is done literally and only at the beginning of the command line. So what do you want to do? Create macros for `dir` to `cls` with 1, 2, 3, ..., 8188 spaces before it?

Answer (score 0):

Blacklisting almost never works, and it certainly isn't going to in this case.  You can, for example, list the files in a directory simply by pressing TAB repeatedly.

Instead, use whitelisting.  Write a console application that takes user input, checks that the input is a command that the user is allowed to run, and if so, passes that command to the shell - or, better still, implement the "approved" commands yourself, so that (a) there can't be any trickery with special characters, and (b) you can remove cmd.exe from the approved applications list - you *are* using software restriction policy, right?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could figure out how to make your DOSKEY macro idea work (I don't think you can), it would be pointless. Your users could easily circumvent the restriction by creating the following batch file:

```
@dir %*
```

DOSKEY macros do not work within batch files, so there is nothing to stop the batch file from executing. And your users could name the batch file anything they want, so you would have a devil of a time policing.